# c++: atomic variable's value is invalid when saved in local variable

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, stl, synchronization

I defined atomic variable *current* inside some Obj-C file:

```
std::atomic<long long> current;
```

after that it was initiated:

```
current=4;
```

After that the variable became accessible by number of threads.
Some threads modified the variable like this:

```
current=(current.fetch_add(1))%4;
```

While other threads modified the variable in different way:

```
current.fetch_add(1);
if(current>=4){
    current=0;
}
```

Finally next line is executed:

```
long long cs=current;
```

At this point something strange happened: it appears in debugger that *cs* is 4 while *current* has different value, usually 1.
My expectation was that *cs* should have the latest value of *current* and should never be greater than 3.
I checked all other instances of *current*; they are not many and used properly everywhere.
What am I missing?

Comment: Improper expectations of atomic behaviour.  Races between reading and writing.

Comment: typo only, nothing else.

Comment: There can be many execution paths that will produce the observed results. The shown access patterns are fundamentally broken, for their stated purpose.

Comment: Side note: `current=4;` is assignment, not initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atomic values are not synchronisation primitives. One of possible execution flows:

```
current.fetch_add(1);  // T1
long long cs=current;  // T2
if(current>=4){  // T1
    current=0;
}
```

And

```
auto tmp = current.fetch_add(1);  // T1
long long cs=current;  // T2
current=tmp%4;  // T1
```

The solution is in using mutexes or spin locks with compare-exchange.

Answer (score -1):

This is a scenario which is very likely to happen in a multithreaded environment. Assume only 2 threads, the main thread which I called here THREAD-2 and a worker thread THREAD-1. Let's start with current having the value 3, and now it's being incremented by THREAD-1, while THREAD-2 is updating the variable cs.

```
THREAD-1:    current.fetch_add(1);
THREAD-2:    cs = current;
THREAD-1:    if(current>=4){ current=0; }
```

as you can see cs gets it's value when current is 4.

Also, this is not an objective-c issue, this is C++ alone.